# why is my for loop printing 2 at each iteration if b has not even been defined as a placeholder in the for loop declaration?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I am fairly new to python and I just learned about tuple unpacking, so I was playing around with this concept and got a weird result.

```
nList = [(1,2),4,5,6]
for a in nList:
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

I was expecting my program to crash since b is not defined as a placeholder and even if it was only the first element of my list is a tuple, but instead, I got the following result:

```
(1, 2)
2
4
2
5
2
6
2
```

Comment: you must have had a variable `b` left over in memory from something you were doing earlier. and it had a value of `2`. Do these same steps in a fresh session/kernel.

Comment: Please post the full source code.

Comment: The code doesn't look correct to me. Are you sure that's your actual code? Do you have `b` define somewhere else in your script?

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the variable **b** in your code, because of which it is using some garbage value of b from memory (which is 2). To avoid such scenarios you must initialize your variables with some value (or 0) in start of your code before using them.